# Styled components - Force passing attribute to dom

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

Styled component is filtering attributes passed to dom to known html attributes. How can I prevent it from filtering out a specific attribute, without affecting any other attribute? So pass attribute "foo" to dom, but for any other attribute use default behaviour.
`ShouldForwardProp` will change default behaviour.